# Bad hour error crontab

Tags: fedora, cron

I would like to execute a command every first friday of the month, at 10:30.
I generated this crontab line with https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

```
0 30 10 ? * 6#1 *
```

When I add this line, I get this error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.4JuoKE":2: bad hour
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

Can anyone provide some feedback what I am doing wrong?

This is my complete crontab file:

```
*/5 * * * * ~/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
0 30 10 ? * 6#1 * zpool scrub data >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I am running fedora 32.

Comment: That site is for http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/, not your usual cron implementations on Linux.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Does a regular cron implementation support the "first day of the month"?

Comment: First day, yes, that's just a `1` in the day-of-month field. First Friday, no, you'll have to check in the script if that's the case.

Comment: @muru, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Specifying a DOW and a DOM will execute the command when EITHER is matched. Use a test as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37628629/5114441) : e.g. use the range DOM-range 1-7 and test for "Friday".

Comment: See `man 5 crontab`. You're trying to pass `30` as the hour. There are more incompatibilities, I think.

Comment: @Fiximan, thanks a lot! I ended up adding this: 
30 10 * * 5 test $(date '+%d') -lt 7 zpool scrub data >/dev/null 2>&1